# listagg oracle selecting insert statements

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I'd like to create insert statements using dynamic select.

The result now is:

```
insert into T_TRAINING_STUDY (C_STUDYINTRAININGID,C_TRAININGOFSTUDYID,CREATED,ID,LASTCHANGED,SERIAL) values (,608089239,sysdate, seq_id_generator.nextval, sysdate, 0 );
insert into T_TRAINING_STUDY (C_STUDYINTRAININGID,C_TRAININGOFSTUDYID,CREATED,ID,LASTCHANGED,SERIAL) values (,608089260,sysdate, seq_id_generator.nextval, sysdate, 0 );
insert into T_TRAINING_STUDY (C_STUDYINTRAININGID,C_TRAININGOFSTUDYID,CREATED,ID,LASTCHANGED,SERIAL) values (598477608,,sysdate, seq_id_generator.nextval, sysdate, 0 );
```

The desired result would be:

```
insert into T_TRAINING_STUDY (C_STUDYINTRAININGID,C_TRAININGOFSTUDYID,CREATED,ID,LASTCHANGED,SERIAL) values (598477608,608089239,sysdate, seq_id_generator.nextval, sysdate, 0 );
insert into T_TRAINING_STUDY (C_STUDYINTRAININGID,C_TRAININGOFSTUDYID,CREATED,ID,LASTCHANGED,SERIAL) values (598477608,608089260,sysdate, seq_id_generator.nextval, sysdate, 0 );
```

I know the problem is that group by unable to work because of the OTKCTEC_N_2022 in the where. But how can resolve this? I have plenty of m.c_code from a file in this format/sample/pair.
Thank you!

```
select 'insert into T_TRAINING_STUDY (C_STUDYINTRAININGID,C_TRAININGOFSTUDYID,CREATED,ID,LASTCHANGED,SERIAL) values ('||
    listagg (s.id||','||t.id) within group (order by s.id) ||',sysdate, seq_id_generator.nextval, sysdate, 0 );' as cc
from t_module m
left join t_study s on s.ID=m.id
left join T_TRAINING t on t.id=m.id
where m.c_code 
in('OTKCTEC-OTKBTES_N_2022','OTKCTEC_N_2022','OTKBNNK-OTKCTEC_N_2022','OTKCTEC_N_2022')
group by m.c_code
;


--m.id          m.c_moduletype   m.c_code
--608089239     37001           OTKBNNK-OTKCTEC_N_2022
--608089260     37001           OTKCTEC-OTKBTES_N_2022
--598477608     37002           OTKCTEC_N_2022
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output for this sample data. It is impossible to guess why "group by unable to work because of the OTKCTEC_N_2022 in the where" and what is your data model where module identifier is equal to training identifier

Comment: Also`listagg` looks strange here: you specify a static number of columns and should have to provide exactly the same number of values. If you know the number of values upfront, then you may explicitly concatenate those values without aggregation

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing both s.id and t.id with m.id in the below statement but your expected output is different.

```
 left join t_study s on s.ID=m.id
 left join T_TRAINING t on t.id=m.id
```

My calculated guess is you have to compare some other column like the below

```
 left join t_study s on s.c_moduletype=m.c_moduletype
 left join T_TRAINING t on t.c_moduletype=m.c_moduletype
```

Based on your input if only one id is there to compare then Ideally, you can use only one column for m.id instead of using the s.id and t.id in the target table but if the target table is already in production you can use something like the below as a workaround

```
listagg (nvl(s.id,t.id)||','||nvl(t.id,s.id))
```

Comment: unfortunately a I dont have anything else to compare just id to id